# Is the following javascript safe from arbitrary code execution?

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, xss

I'm contributing to a javascript framework which has the equivalent of the following code:

```
eval("'" + user_input.replace(/'/g, "&#39;") + "'");
```

I know this is terrible -- no need to persuade me. What I want to know is, can I inject arbitrary code here?

At first glance the `user_input.replace("'", "&#39;")` would seem to prevent me from breaking out of the string. However I can pass in newlines e.g. `\nalert(123)\n`, but then the result is always a syntax error, e.g.

```
'
alert(123)
'
```

Is there actually a vector for code injection here, other than just causing a syntax error?

Comment: I can almost guarantee there is SOME kind of injection you can do here...

Comment: Everytime you use `eval()`, you might as well just assume it's not safe at all, and if eval'ing user input, you probably did so many other mistakes that it's a hackers wet dream.

Comment: You don't need to persuade me of this. I just want to provide a good example to the devs of an actual attack.

Comment: `user_input = 'window.location="http://example.com"'`

Comment: @Matt that wouldn't do anything. That's eval-ing `'window.location="http://example.com"'`, so it's just a string

Comment: @Matt: doesn't work. It's being wrapped in single quotes and treated as a string -- see above code.

Comment: The thing I'm wondering is what the heck is user_input, and why do you pass it to eval like this ?

Comment: @bluepnume The single quotes are not part of the string, so are not escaped.

Comment: I bet there is something on the cheat sheet:  https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: @adeneo: it's an example. user_input could be ANYTHING. I want to find a value for user_input which could result in arbitrary code execution.

Comment: It does seem rather safe to me, but you wouldn't really be able to eval anything at all, so I don't see how you could use it for something useful ?

Comment: what's the context? Surely there's more to this than just an eval evaluating a string, because that wouldn't do anything. Can you show us the rest of this?

Comment: @Markasoftware: I prefer to provide a little anonymity for the project until this is fixed. The example code is a simplified version of the actual code, but has the exact same effect.

Comment: @Markasoftware Ok sorry you and bluepnume are right - it is just treated as a string

Comment: And eval'ing that string will never do anything, so you're pretty safe, but at the same time you will never be able to pass anything to the eval function yourself and have it executed, so it's pretty much useless ?

Comment: @adeneo it looks like just a string...but his question is if there's some way to break out of that string

Comment: perhaps there is something to do with the backspace (`\b`) character that could be used to delete the starting quote?

Comment: @Markasoftware - doesn't matter what you pass in if you can't break out of the quotes, and entity encoding them like this does a good job of preventing that. Again, the disadvantage is that the eval is now always passed a value that is treated as a string, so it doesn't do anything at all, even with valid input, and it's hard to hack something that has no actual functionality.

Comment: @adeneo but if you could, in some way, break out of the string, then it wouldn't just be `something that has no actual functionality` anymore

Comment: @Markasoftware - But you probably can't. Adding the extra quotes and the entity encoding makes sure of that, as whatever is passed in is just treated as a string, and eval does nothing. The point being, you can't use it for anything like that, it has no meaning in the actual code as it does absolutely nothing. Usually eval will eval code, and as such it's vulnerable, but in this case it's not vulnerable as it does nothing at all, no matter what you pass in, so you probably can't hack it, and you can't use it for anything either.

Comment: Note that `eval()`ing a string constant isn't **completely** useless — it returns the string value it evaluated, which could be useful if the string has escape sequences like `\n` that need to be interpreted. As my answer points out, though, backslashes can also cause some problems if you're not careful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While this is undoubtedly a worrisome pattern, it's safe if used exactly in the way described. The only character that can terminate a single-quoted string in Javascript is the single quote character. So long as that character does not appear in the string interpolated into the single quotes, it cannot possibly be interpreted as anything other than a string.

About the worst thing I can think of that you could do is end a string with a backslash, which would result in an unterminated string, e.g. if `user_input` were:

```
example\
```

then the evaluated code would be

```
'example\'
```

which would result in a syntax error, because the string contained in the `eval` is never terminated. However, if the real `eval` is actually more complex, **this is exploitable**. For example, if the code were:

```
var escaped_input = user_input.replace(/'/g, "&39;");
eval("'" + escaped_input + "' some more stuff '" + escaped_input + "'");
```

then it **could** be exploited with an input like:

```
; alert(1); // \
```

which would result in:

```
'; alert(1); // \' some more stuff '; alert(1); // \'
                                      ^^^^^^^^^
```

in which the underlined content would be evaluated, because the quote that was supposed to exit the string was escaped, turning the next single quote into a *closing* quote! To be safe, I'd recommend escaping or replacing backslashes if possible (unless you're explicitly trying to use `eval()` to deal with them, in which case you might just catch the exception).

Comment: Yeah in the node.js repl I can get it to pause waiting for the end of the string with `user_input = "console.log(42)\\"`.

Comment: That doesn't sound quite right. `eval()` on a malformed input should throw a SyntaxError, not pause the interpreter.

Comment: Yes, in a program, but in the repl it just waits for you to type more.

Comment: That shouldn't happen. `eval()` is supposed to be self-contained — it shouldn't be *able* to trigger the REPL to start doing anything.

Comment: I'm just saying I testing the backslash by starting a node repl and running the `eval` there. That's all. It ends up not even getting to the eval because it's still waiting for the quote to close the string literal. That's all.

Comment: Brilliant answer, thanks duskwuff. I hadn't considered the possibility of two strings in a row.